# Laravel routing: how to pass parameter/arguments from one controller to controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have two controller and one controller calls another. I finish some processing on Controller 1 and want to pass the data to controller 2 for further processing.

**Controller 1:**

```
public function processData() 
  {
    $paymenttypeid = “123”;
    $transid = “124”;
    return Redirect::action('Controller2@getData');
  }
```

**Controller 2:**

```
public function getData($paymenttypeid, $transid ) 
{
}
```

**Error:**

```
Missing argument 1 for Controller2::getData()
```

How do I pass arguments from Controller 1 to Controller 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is really not a good way to do it.

However, if you really want to redirect and pass data it would be easier if they were like this:

```
<?php

class TestController extends BaseController {

    public function test1()
    {
        $one = 'This is the first variable.';
        $two = 'This is the second variable';

        return Redirect::action('TestController@test2', compact('one', 'two'));
    }

    public function test2()
    {
        $one = Request::get('one');
        $two = Request::get('two');

        dd([$one, $two]);
    }

}
```

*note* that I am not requiring arguments in the controller method.

There are many ways to skin the cat, and what you are trying to do is not a good one. I'd recommend starting off by looking at how to use service objects instead, as described in [this video](https://laracasts.com/lessons/controller-cleanup), and countless tutorials.

> If you're not careful, very quickly, your controllers can become unwieldy. Worse, what happens when you want to call a controller method from another controller? Yikes! One solution is to use service objects, to isolate our domain from the HTTP layer.
>
> -Jeffrey Way

Comment: Thank You, I am having a look at service objects.