# How to pass and retrieve data between two controllers in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, scope

I'm trying to get to grips with Laravel and not finding the documentation any help at all. It seems to assume you know so much instead of actually walking new users through each section step by step.

I've got to the point where I need to make an internal call to another class, and sticking with MVC I can't seem to do what should be a simple thing.

My code:

```
class UsersController extends BaseController {

    protected $layout   = 'layouts.templates.page';

    protected $messages;

    public function getIndex()
    {
        $input = array('where', array('field' => 'email', 'operator' => '=', 'value' => 'tony@fluidstudiosltd.com'));
        $request = Request::create('user/read', 'GET');
        $users = json_decode(Route::dispatch($request)->getContent());
        var_dump($users); exit;
        $this->pageTitle = 'Fluid Customer Status :: Admin Users';
        $this->content = View::make('layouts.admin.users');
    }

}

Class UserController extends Base Controller
    public function getRead()
    {
        $userId = (int) Request::segment(3);
        if ($userId)
        {
            $user = User::findOrFail($userId);
            return $user;
        }
        else
        {
            $users = new User;
            var_dump(Input::all()); exit;
            if (Input::has('where'))
            {
                var_dump(Input::get('where')); exit;
            }
            return $users->get();
        }
    }
```

Why isn't the input data from UsersController@getIndex available in UserController@getRead

Comment: I don't know about Laravel in particular but generally you want to avoid making controller to controller calls. Any functionality that you need in multiple controller methods should be abstracted out.

Comment: @JohnP HMVC is based around making controller to controller calls, as one controller cannot talk to another controllers view or model. How can any website function without controllers talking to each other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel routing: how to pass parameter/arguments from one controller to controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28059775/laravel-routing-how-to-pass-parameter-arguments-from-one-controller-to-controll)

Comment: My question is not a duplicate as that question is about redirecting from one controller to another. I don't want to redirect to another controller, I want to make a call to one, receive a response back and keep going with my current controller.

Comment: @Styphon Laravel is *not* designed for HMVC. So you are going to have issues with doing it that way. What you want is something like the Command Bus or similar - https://github.com/laracasts/Commander

Comment: If laravel can't do something this damn simple out of the box then it's not the framework for me...

Comment: Found what I needed, but it's still a bodge job - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597420/how-can-i-access-query-string-parameters-for-requests-ive-manually-dispatched-i#answer-16600493

Comment: please be specific, you mean that you want to use the service  that offers from another controller .